# Project build error: Unknown packaging: bundle

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, pdfbox

I am trying to build [pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) but I can't seem to resolve this Maven error:

> `Project build error: Unknown packaging: bundle`

Which appear only in the sub-projects `pdfbox` and `preflight`.

I have installed the m2e connector and build helper and as suggested [here](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg03783.html) I've installed Tycho but it didn't help either.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging> <!-- Project build error: Unknown packaging: bundle -->

    <!-- ... -->

    <dependencies>
        <!-- ... -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
       <!-- ... -->
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xmx128m</argLine>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>org/apache/pdfbox/TestAll.java</exclude>
                    <exclude>org/apache/pdfbox/util/TestPDFToImage.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <java.util.logging.config.file>src/test/resources/logging.properties</java.util.logging.config.file>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Include-Resource>
                        {maven-resources},
                        META-INF=target/maven-shared-archive-resources/META-INF,
                        org/apache/pdfbox/resources=target/classes/org/apache/pdfbox/resources
                    </Include-Resource>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.rat</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-rat-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>src/main/resources/org/apache/pdfbox/resources/afm/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>src/main/resources/org/apache/pdfbox/resources/icc/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>src/main/resources/org/apache/pdfbox/resources/glyphlist/glyphlist.txt</exclude>
                    <exclude>src/main/resources/org/apache/pdfbox/resources/glyphlist/zapfdingbats.txt</exclude>
                    <exclude>src/main/resources/META-INF/services/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>src/test/resources/input/rendering/*.ai</exclude>
                    <exclude>src/test/resources/output/*</exclude>
                    <exclude>release.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>src/test/resources/org/apache/pdfbox/encryption/*.der</exclude>
                    <exclude>src/test/resources/org/apache/pdfbox/encryption/*.pfx</exclude>
                    <exclude>src/test/resources/org/apache/pdfbox/filter/*.bin</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: You omitted your plugins. Have you added OSGi support?

Comment: I have now added the plugins. I am not sure. How can I tell? (No experience with OSGi)

Comment: What maven version do you use? It needs at least version 2. Are you able to build outside of eclipse, i.e. by entering "mvn clean install" ?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am using the m2e plugin for Eclipse Luna. It says  v1.5.0 but I am not sure whether this is the version of the plugin or Maven. Assuming this is the Maven version than this might be the problem and I'll have to try to get v2 running here ..

Comment: Non of the answers below seem to help for https://github.com/rc-dukes/dukes/issues/22

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Move `maven-bundle-plugin` outside of `pluginManagement`. Maven will only look for `<build><plugins>` and uses `pluginManagement` for additional information.

Comment: Removed my last comment: This worked! Led to another Maven problem, but worked for the bundle error.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, solved my error of unknown package for mule

Answer (score 37):

in my case it was already outside of a plugin-management tag. it was solved for me by adding

`<extensions>true</extensions>`

to the plugin tag

Answer (score 6):

try this for your pom.xml, it works for mine:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions> <!--add this line-->
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Export-Package>com.demo.hello.*</Export-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you give explanation of your answer? why should this fix the error? also what is com.demo.hello?

Comment: Forget com.demo.hello, it come from my code, you should set yours. `<extensions>true</extensions>` can refer to [this](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugins-lifecycle.html) at 11.6.3.

Comment: it said, If you create a plugin which defines a new packaging type and a customized lifecycle, Maven won’t know anything about it until you add the plugin to your project’s POM and set the extensions element to true.

Answer (score 0):

In case of

https://github.com/rc-dukes/dukes/issues/22

there is a very strange behavior. We thought we could fix the issue by modifying the permissions. But infact it seems to be connected with some strange travis behavior where only every second or third build succeeds - even if no relevant content has been changed. We don't have a solution yet but would mention the work-around here to just retry a few times. Any hint on what the real fix is would be welcome.